# Model Theory - Equivalence of formulas using automorphisms

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\mathbf Q$ denote the additive group of rational numbers, i.e. the structure $\mathbf Q = (\mathbb Q;+,0)$. Let $L$ be the language of $\mathbf Q$ and let $T$ be the complete theory of $\mathbf Q$. By considering automorphisms of $\mathbf Q$ given that every formula in F1(L) is E1(T)-equivalent to exactly one of the four formulas $v_1=v_1$, $v_1=0$, $v_1\neq 0$, $v_1\neq v_1$.

Prove that there are infinitely many E2(T) - equivalence classes of formulas in F2(T)?

Comment: What is $F_1(L), E_1(T)$? Also, what did you try?

Comment: F1(L) is the set of L formulas with (up to) 1 free variable.  E1(T) is the equivalence relation defined by; two formulas a,b are equivalent if T logically implies that for all v1 , a iff b

Comment: And I can't do start the first part.  I've done the last bit

Comment: Can you describe the orbits of $\mathbb Q$ under the automorphism group of the structure?

Comment: And when you write "-v1=0", do you really mean $-v_1=0$? This is $E_1(T)$ equivalent to $v_1=0$, so the statement cannot be true. This should be $v_1\neq 0$, I guess.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format the equations, the ones with a minus before them are just meant to be negations of the other two

Comment: Right, I edited your question accordingly. Do you have ideas about my other comment?

Comment: Was my answer helpful? If so, please accept it, so that your question leaves the "unanswered" list! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $\frac{p}{q}, \frac{p'}{q'}$ with $p,p',q,q'\neq 0$, there exists an automorphism of $\mathbf Q$ which maps $\frac{p}{q}$ to $\frac{p'}{q'}$. Indeed, the map $x\mapsto \frac{qp'}{q'p}x$ is an automorphism of the structure (i.e., it is bijective and preserve $0$ and $+$ in both directions).
This means that there are two orbits of points of $\mathbb Q$ under automorphisms of $\mathbf Q$: there is $\{0\}$, and there is $\{\frac{p}{q} \mid p,q\neq 0\}$.

Now, let $\phi(v)$ be a $L$-formula with one free variable. Remark that if $\frac{p}{q}$ satisfies $\phi$, every point $\frac{p'}{q'}$ in the same orbit as $\frac{p}{q}$ also satisfies $\phi$, by the very definition of an automorphism. I can't stress enough how this is important: the set of points $\frac{p}{q}$ for which $\phi$ hold is a union of orbits of $\mathbb Q$ under $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbf Q)$.

So what kind of formulas with one free variable can we have?

- There are the formulas that are satisfied by no points in $\mathbb Q$, and these ones are equivalent to $v_1\neq v_1$,
- there are the formulas that are satisfied by every point of $\mathbb Q$, which are equivalent to $v_1=v_1$.

These formulas are those that contain either $0$ orbits, or $2$ orbits. It remains those that contain precisely $1$ orbit of points. These ones are:

- The formula that are satisfied only by $0$, and these formulas are equivalent to $v_1=0$,
- and finally, there remains the formulas that are satisfied by the points different than $0$, and those are equivalent to $v_1\neq 0$.